# How to create links using JSON that, when clicked, show up in a separate <div>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I'm using jQuery to create a ul of different beer types using JSON. How can I make is so that when a user clicks one of the li, it duplicates into a separate div? 
FYI: I'm pretty new to jQuery, but familiar w/ HTML.

```
$(styles.types).each(function(){
    var output="<li><a class=move>" + this.beerType+"</a></li>";
    $('#styleList').append("<ul>"+output+"</ul>");
});

$('#styleList').on('click', ".move", function(){
    var floatInfo="<li>" + this.beerType+"</li>";
    $('#floater').append("<ul>"+floatInfo+"</ul>");
});
```

What am I doing wrong here? I can get the list to show up, no problem, but clicking doesn't seem to do anything.

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/syndac/nvEVn/)

Comment: You should indent your code.

Comment: JSON is a data format, so has nothing to do with the functionality you are creating. Nor does the code you've pasted use `getJSON`.

Comment: is `styles` the JSON you get from `getJSON()`?

Comment: @conca, yes. It's styles.json

Comment: @IMSoP, my bad. I copy/pasted from jsfiddle. I _will_ be using getJSON for the final product since I can't through jsfiddle.

Comment: @user2773449 Can we see the jsFiddle then?

Comment: @IMSoP, sure thing. [link](http://jsfiddle.net/syndac/nvEVn/). I shortened the actual JSON, but otherwise, it's the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this code:

```
//Put JSON on DIV
var output = "";
$(styles.types).each(function(){
    output += "<li><a class='move'>" + this.beerType+"</a></li>";
});
$('#styleList').append("<ul>"+output+"</ul)>");

//Click event
$('#styleList').on('click', ".move", function(){
    $('#floater').append("<ul><li>"+$(this).html()+"</li></ul>");
});
```

The working JSFidlle: http://jsfiddle.net/Z5dEC/

Hope it helps!

Comment: Any version of this that doesn't use getJSON? I'm trying to test in JSFiddle and JSFiddle doesn't allow for external JSON.

Comment: Thanks! Now, me being new to JavaScript--any chance I can get an explanation of why yours works and mine didn't?

Comment: Each function has a scope, so `this` references a different object deppending the function you are calling. In the first one, `this` is the JSON object, but in the second one, `this` is the clicked link, so you cant call `this.beerType` because that link doesnt have the property `beerType`.

Comment: And in the fiddle you have `<div class="floater">` but you used the selector `$('#floater')`, I change it to `<div id="floater">`. The query `$('#floater')` looks for the element with `id='floater'` and the query `$('.floater')` looks for all the elements with `class='floater'`.

Answer (score 3):

I guess it should be:

```
$('#styleList').on('click', ".move", function(){
    var floatInfo=...
    $('#floater').append("<ul>"+floatInfo+"</ul>"); // <--- floatInfo, not output; output is undefined here
});
```

---

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8aLrf/

You must change `$("#floater")` to `$(".floater")` and `this.beerType` to `$(this).text()`.

Comment: In the question, `floatInfo = ..+this.beerType+..`, but in that scope `this` is an HTML tag.

Comment: @nikos, I changed it to `floatInfo`, but it still doesn't seem to work (can't believe I missed it in the first place).

Comment: @conca, I'm assuming you meant `floatInfo="<li>+this.beerType+"</li>";`? I'm new at this so I really wasn't sure...

Comment: @conca Does it display an error now? Can you include the relevant part of your HTML? Can you put a `console.log` inside the function (one at the beginning and one at the end), to make sure it gets called?

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos, see [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/syndac/nvEVn/). I tried using the `console.log`s and it seems that it gets called the whole way through. Could be doing it wrong, though--pretty new at JavaScript.

Comment: I doesnt have the HTML, I'm trying to help. I told that the second `this.beerType` of the question is bad, it must be `$(this).html()`